# Windsor IoC Named Injections: Constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I would like to know how I can accomplish the following within Windsor. I previously used AutoFac with the following code, which worked perfectly, but I'm not sure how I can accomplish the same thing in Windsor:

```
// named injection registrations
builder.RegisterType<FoodMarketProvider>().Keyed<IMarketProvider>(MarketProviders.Food.GetDescription()).PropertiesAutowired();            
builder.RegisterType<ClothsMarketProvider>().Keyed<IMarketProvider>(MarketProviders.Cloths.GetDescription()).PropertiesAutowired();
```

So in my manager I can use `IIndex` to get hold of the named injections:

```
// market manager constructor
public MarketManager(IIndex<string, IMarketProvider> serviceDictionary)
```

Example of usage:

```
public Task<dynamic> GetResellerProducts(MarketProviders market)
{
    var marketProvider = base.ServiceDictionary[market.GetDescription()];
    return marketProvider.GetProducts();
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The `IIndex` is unique to Autofac and Windsor doesn't have an exact counterpart. [Type Factories](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/typed-factory-facility-interface-based.md) which are a more general tool are commonly used in those scenarios. You can configure them to lookup components by name in a similar fashion to `IIndex` [as shown in the documentation](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/typed-factory-facility-interface-based.md#custom-itypedfactorycomponentselectors).